# Show that $\hat{f}$ is analytic at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The Riemann removable singularities theorem states that,

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the deleted neighborhood $N_0(z_0,r)$ and $f$ is bounded on $N_0(z_0,r')$ for some $0<r'<r$.

Then there exists an analytic function $\hat{f}$ on $N(z_0,r)$ such that $\hat{f} = f$ on $N_0 (z_0,r)$.

$\hat{f}$ can be described as,

$\hat{f}(z) = f(z) \ $ if $ \ z\in N_0(z_0,r)$

$\hat{f}(z) = \lim_{\zeta \rightarrow z_0} f(\zeta) \ $ if $\ z = z_0$.

How to show that $\hat{f}$ is analytic at $z_0$ ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity?

Answer (score 0):

take the following contour: Outer circle $C_1$ with center $z_0$ and radius r, inner circle $C_2$: center $z_0$  and radius $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and 2 lines from $C_1$ to $C_2$ and then from $C_2$ to $C_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f$ has a Laurent series around $z_0$. The principal part of it will be ... because $f$ is bounded near $z_0$.

Comment: The principal part vanishes. Can i have more hint on what to do next?

Comment: @LittleRookie, if the principal part vanishes, $f =$ a Taylor series in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: I cant solve it :(